# Generate public/private keys AND sign them with Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA in Perl

Tags: perl, openssl

I am used to generate keys with OpenSSL via shell, this way:

```
my $ssk="a29bRwoA73xZGeBc";
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout "/etc/ssl/$ssk.key" -out "/etc/ssl/$ssk.csr"
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in "/etc/ssl/$ssk.csr" -signkey "/etc/ssl/$ssk.key" -out "/etc/ssl/$ssk.crt"
```

Now I need to perform this action via PERL, but I have no idea if the below code can at least implement the 1st line:

```
my $ssk="a29bRwoA73xZGeBc";

# I didn't use Crypt::OpenSSL::Random, as I didn't found where it comes to action
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
my $rsa=Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->generate_key(2048);
my $rsa_pub=Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($rsa->get_public_key_x509_string());
my $rsa_prv=Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($rsa->get_private_key_string());
my $cipher=$rsa->encrypt($rsa_pub);
my $plain=$rsa->encrypt($cipher);
my $sigt=$rsa_prv->sign($plain); # This seems to be part of the 2nd line in shell code, but maybe I am wrong.
unless($rsa->verify($plain,$sigt)) { die "Failed to create keys"; }

# Here is the issue:
&SaveFile("/etc/ssl/$ssk.key",$plain,0400); # Is it correct?
&SaveFile("/etc/ssl/$ssk.csr",$cipher,0400); # How about this?

# How do I proceed to implement the 2nd line in the shell code?
```

Note that the part of Crypt::OpenSSL::Random and saving to key files is not docmented...

Thanks a lot

Comment: The openssl command are __not__ about creating and __signing key__. They are about creating a __key and certificate__. And instead of trying to implement this with `Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA` you could just use [IO::Socket::SSL::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL::Utils) with functions like `KEY_create_rsa` and `CERT_create`. Also, creating a CSR is not required to generate a certificate. It is only common since the owner of the certificate and the CA are controlled by different entities and the CSR is the way for the owner to request a new certificate.

Comment: Ok, I have read the spec of IO::Socket::SSL::Utils, I found the KEY_create_rsa, then it creates "pem" file. How I continue from here to CERT_create? I didn't found anything about it, or a small example... Also, then: How do I add the data like: Address, company name, etc?

Comment: See for example https://metacpan.org/source/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-2.066/certs/create-certs.pl which creates a certificate hierarchy with root CA, intermediate, leaf certificates etc.